# Pyspark read selected date files from date hierarchy storage

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to read multiple CSV files using Pyspark, data are processed by Amazon Kinesis Firehose so they are wrote in the format below.

```
s3bucket/ 
    YYYY/
        mm/
            dd/
                hh/
                    files.gz
                    files.gz
                    files.gz
```

I'm actually using this code to read for a full day (e.g 15/01/2019), with regex:

```
data = spark.read.format("s3selectJson").options(compression="GZIP", multiline=True) \
    .load("s3://s3bucket/2019/01/15/*.gz".format(datetime_object.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")))
```

My question is, how can i read multiple days of data knowing the dates I want? Is there an automatic way or should I make a regex for the dates I need?

EDIT:
What I am looking for is the inverse function of the DataFrameWriter.partitionBy(*cols) method in the documentation below
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=regex#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a function for it, however, this is a workaround:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime("2019-01-31", '%Y-%m-%d')
delta_days = 10
base_bucket = "s3://s3bucket/{}/*/*.gz"
bucket_names = []
for date in [datetime_object - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, delta_days)]:
    bucket_names.append(base_bucket.format(date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")))
```

Luckily, the `.load()` function takes a list as argument of source paths, so I am generating every path based on the dates I need and giving it to the load function.

```
data = spark.read.format("csv").options(compression="GZIP") \
        .load(bucket_names)
```

Answer (score 2):

I worry, there is no way to do that.

If your data is structured like below (with month=, year=...), we call it as partition.

```
s3bucket/ 
    year=YYYY/
        month=mm/
            day=dd/
                hour=hh/
                    files.gz
                    files.gz
                    files.gz
```

And you can easily load your data (In your case by some specific days)

```
data = spark.read.format("s3selectJson").options(compression="GZIP", multiline=True) \
  .load("s3://s3bucket/")

data_days = data.filter("day in (10, 20)")
```

With partition, Spark only load your specific days, not all days.

Comment: My problem is that, being a very large amount of files, I wished to load as little data as possible, to avoid having to query them all afterwards